# InfoPath form Problem

Tags: infopath, 2013

I modified new form with infopath but it says:

> InfoPath cannot submit the form bewcause it contains errors. Errors
>   are marked with either a red asterisk (required fields) or a red,
>   dashed broder (invalid values).

**But when I add the items with List>Edit they are added successfully.** The problem is the new form which edited in InfoPath. Because I can't add anything with New Form.

What should I do?

Comment: Does the IP form show all forms of the list? If a required field is not displayed, the form won't submit unless you use a rule to fill the required field.

Comment: It is the same template that is used both for New and Edit modes

Comment: I open the default form with InfoPath from Ribbon and then I edit the form with IP and I published it successfully. The new edited form displays but when I try to submit this warning appears and don't allow me to add something. It wants me to fix the errors.